# Correct position to put search bar in item catalogue

Tags: gui-design

I am building a e-commerce platform which requires a user to shop around for their desired features. I realise a search bar is an important feature, but at the moment I don't know where to put it. I would appreciate any advice:

Main view:

[image]

Dropdown:

[image]

Filter:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do what is likely to make the most intuitive sense to your users. Anyone answering here won't know the larger context of how the rest of this site/page is working, so we'll have to make some assumptions.

I'm a sample size of one, but the first place I'd intuitively look for search is the upper-right area, like across from "Select your features". After that I'd look in the filter/dropdown area.

If it has to go in that area, I think I would personally put it on the right half of that section. If it's on the left half, somewhere near that filter, it might confuse users - they could think that the filter and the search are working in conjunction.

For instance, this will be familiar to users - this tells me I'm searching within "Books"

[image: example of filtered search UI from Amazon]

And if that's not the functionality you're providing...

Speaking of your filter: that dropdown should be clearly labeled. I wouldn't know what "All" is supposed to be without clicking on it.

Maybe something like this.

[image: example changes]

(I'd also suggest you darken up those light grays to be a good #a11y - they seem very low contrast. You can test that with a [contrast checker](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker).)

Hopefully that's all helpful!

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

When you can't find a logical place to put navigation elements, there are more options out of the static.

Like an **Expandable Search Form** that you can put it at the left / over the title:

[image]

*(This example is over a web menu)*